# Infinite counter-examples to Borsuk conjecture

Tags: discrete-geometry

When I formulate the Borsuk conjecture in the form of a coloring problem, Aigner told me that the formulation is not quite correct: It only works if the set is finite.  He's right.

All the constructions for counter-examples to Borsuk conjecture use finite set (thanks to Larman's conjecture?).  It seems to me that we might obtain infinite counter-examples from them by, for example, taking convex hulls.  Am I right?

So what do we known about the existence of infinite counter-examples from the existence of finite counter-examples, and vice versa? Can we somehow use [de Brujin–Erdős Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory))？ Is it possible that, in some dimensions, only infinite counter-examples exist?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%27s_conjecture), Borsuk conjecture is known to be true for smooth convex bodies, centrally-symmetric bodies and evolution bodies.

Comment: It's strange that for the smooth convex bodies the proof of the Borsuk's conjecture is easy (Hadwiger's result) while the finite case is so dramatically wrong.